# Frequently running queries firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-console

Is it possible to know [Frequently running queries] or [number of reads for given collection or document] in firestore?

I think number of read operations for my application is very high compared to number of users but there seems no way to reconsile.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in reporting on such statistics. If you want them, you'll have to build something yourself on top of the API.

If you'd like help explaining the read operations of your code, reproduce the behavior in an isolated example and update your question to include that. [Creating such an MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is the best way to get help with specific code.

Comment: There is no specific example in my case, but I found at one place EventListener was attached.. In addition to that that class was instantiated multiple time ..  hence there were multiple listeners listening to same query... it is very hard to detect such problem because it can be detected only by code review in firebase.. however in traditional SQL era we had database provider providing frequently fired sql queries (and count) etc.. I was looking for something like that

Answer (score 0):

Firestore query history is available in [Google Cloud Logs](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs) under the resource type "Audited Resource". For me, the exact query is listed in either `protoPayload.request.addTarget.documents.documents` or `protoPayload.request.addTarget.query.parent`.